# Kafka producer posting messages to secondary cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api, failover

Description of proposed cluster setup

- 2 Data centres and each having 5 node Kafka cluster
- Clusters are having the same topics and same producer/consumer instances working with it
- There is no data replication across the clusters. So data in Cluster 1 and 2 is distinct
- There is no message affinity required. [It will not make any difference functionally if either the Producer 1 were to start posting message to Cluster 2 and vice versa]

What we want to achieve is, Lets say Producer 1 posts a message asynchronously to Cluster 1, but receives a negative acknowledgment ( after all the retry timeout has occurred). This is easily detected in the producer callback method

On receiving this failure, We use another KafkaTemplate (having details of Cluster 2) to be used by producer. Now producer tries posting the same message on to cluster 2 [ It applies other way round as well, if producer 2 unable to post locally , it will send message to cluster 1]

The advantage that we get here is

- message is not lost and posted automatically to the other cluster
- Since this activity occurs for each message, so once the Cluster 1 is back up, automatically Producer 1 is able to send messages to cluster 1

One down side we see is, We are handling the failover logic ourselves by producing to secondary cluster in exception handling block of either Metadata fetch timeout or on Negative acknowledgment

I could not find any where on the net showing a similar setup. Is there is something fundamentally wrong with this approach

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure; just configure 2 sets of infrastructure beans - producer and consumer factories, container factories, templates.

You can't use Boot's auto configuration for that, but you can define the beans yourself.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I was looking just a nod of confirmation on this setup :).  We did do some load testing as well and it works fine